# Points per Inch on IOS device

Tags: ios, ios6

I am trying to convert IOS points to real length(inches).

Im testing this on the New iPad. according to the spec. its width is 7.31 inches and in xcode it has 768 Points, which means it has 768/7.31 = 105 points per inch (horizontally).

From the calculation, a 105-point horizontal line should be displayed as 1 inch on physical screen.

However, when i draw on the screen and measure the distance its shorter that calculated.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [specs](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/), the 7.31 inches is the total width of the device, not the screen.  There is a bezel around the screen to allow the user to hold the iPad without touching interface controls on the screen.

Also, if scroll down a bit, you'll see that the screen is

> - 2048-by-1536 resolution at 264 pixels per inch (ppi)

Comment: Thanks! yea I just realized the display width is 5.82 inch instead of 7.31.

Comment: A side note: "PPI" should really be [Pixels per inch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixels_per_inch) as opposed to "Points-per-Inch" as a "point" is the term used in [typography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)) which can themselves be measured in pixels (which would be affected by the PPI of the screen).